# Java program cannot find a value longer than 3 digits in a list

Tags: java, list

I have a list and want to try to use a search method. It works for values 3 digits or shorter, but will not work for longer numbers. Where am I going wrong?

```html
class ListNode<T> {
   T data; // data for this node
   ListNode<T> nextNode; // reference to the next node in the list
   // constructor creates a ListNode that refers to object
   ListNode(T object) {this(object, null);}
   // constructor creates ListNode that refers to the specified
   // object and to the next ListNode
   ListNode(T object, ListNode<T> node) {
      data = object;
      nextNode = node;
   }
   T getData() {return data;}
   ListNode<T> getNext() {return nextNode;}

}

// class List definition
public class List<T> {
   public ListNode<T> firstNode;
   private ListNode<T> lastNode;
   private String name; // string like "list" used in printing
   // constructor creates empty List with "list" as the name
   public List() {this("list");}
   // constructor creates an empty List with a name
   public List(String listName) {
      name = listName;
      firstNode = lastNode = null;
   }

   // insert item at end of List
   public void insertAtBack(T insertItem) {
      if (isEmpty()) { // firstNode and lastNode refer to same object
         firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
      }
      else { // lastNode's nextNode refers to new node
         lastNode = lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
      }
   }


   public boolean search(ListNode <T> node,T data)
   {
      if (node == null){
         System.out.println("Not found");
         return false;}
      if (node.data == data){
         System.out.println("Found");
         return true;}
      return search(node.nextNode,data);
   }
}
```

Main class:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List <Integer> list=new List<>();
      // insert integers in list
        list.insertAtBack(11);//is found
        list.insertAtBack(10);
        list.insertAtBack(111);
        list.insertAtBack(1234); //value that is not being found
        list.insertAtBack(123);
        

//prep scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a value:");
        int searchInt = input.nextInt();
        //search
        list.search(list.firstNode,searchInt);





   }
}
```

As shown, it works with 10,11, and 123, but not 1234. Any help or direction is appreciated. I think it could be due to not having enough nodes, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in how you are testing for a match between the search term and each value in the list.  To test if the integer value of two `Integer` objects are the same, you have to use `Integer.equals()` rather than `==`.

Change this line of your code:

```
if (node.data. == data) {
```

to:

```
if (node.data.equals(data)) {
```

and you'll get the result that you expect.  The reason that `==` doesn't work is that it is testing if the two values are the exact same object.  This generally won't be the case for two `Integer` objects that contain the same primitive integer value.

The reason that your code seems to work for many of your test values is that Java caches the first N `Integer` objects (I don't know what `N` is) for memory efficiency figuring that these values are very commonly used.  So when you create a new `Integer` object with a small integer value, Java returns the same exact object that represents that value every time you seem to be creating a new object.  So it isn't that you're adding more than 3 items to your list.  It's that one of your values is larger than the largest value `Integer` object that Java caches.

UPDATE: I googled and found that Java caches Integer objects with values in the range `–128 to +127`.

Comment: Thank you! The explanation on the N values were very helpful :)